# Issues creating functions in R

Tags: r, function

I am having problems creating multi step functions in R. My lines of code work when I use them outside the function and plug the information I need into the lines of code, but when I use the function() and plug variables into the lines of code, it errors, usually with error `Error: Result must have length 370, not 0`

For example here is the function I am working with now:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
    stateuse <- hospitaloutcome %>% filter(State == state)
    stateusecols <- stateuse[,c(2,7,11,17,23)]
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('heart attack' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack')
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('heart failure' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure')
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('pneumonia' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia')
    stateusecols$'heart failure' <- as.numeric(stateusecols$'heart failure')
    stateusecols$'pneumonia' <- as.numeric(stateusecols$'pneumonia')
    value <- min(stateusecols$outcome , na.rm=TRUE)
    neededrow <- stateusecols %>% filter(stateusecols$outcome == value)
    hospital <- neededrow[,1]
    hospital
}

#But when I call best('TX','heart attack') it errors with the result must have length 370, not 0
#However when I just do this:

stateuse <- hospitaloutcome %>% filter(State == 'TX')
    stateusecols <- stateuse[,c(2,7,11,17,23)]
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('heart attack' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack')
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('heart failure' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure')
    stateusecols <- stateusecols %>% rename('pneumonia' = 
                                                'Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia')
    stateusecols$'heart failure' <- as.numeric(stateusecols$'heart failure')
    stateusecols$'pneumonia' <- as.numeric(stateusecols$'pneumonia')
    value <- min(stateusecols$'heart attack' , na.rm=TRUE)
    neededrow <- stateusecols %>% filter(stateusecols$'heart attack' == value)
    hospital <- neededrow[,1]
    hospital
#I get my answer, same lines of code, without the function() and the variables I need are in the same 
#spots as the variables defined.
```

I've had this issue over and over with all my functions that I create. Any suggestions?

```
#For reference
 str(stateusecols)
'data.frame':   370 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Hospital.Name: chr  "PROVIDENCE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL" "MEMORIAL HERMANN BAPTIST ORANGE HOSPITAL" "PETERSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER" "CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL -SCOTT & WHITE HEALTHCARE" ...
 $ State        : chr  "TX" "TX" "TX" "TX" ...
 $ heart attack : num  16.1 16.3 15.7 NA 17.4 15.7 12.9 17.4 18.1 16 ...
 $ heart failure: num  9.1 14.3 12.4 10.5 15.1 15.6 11.2 11.8 11.8 9.2 ...
 $ pneumonia    : num  12.4 12.7 14.3 11.9 13.1 10.4 12 11.4 12.1 10.2 ...
```

Comment: You use argument name `outcome`, but in the code you use `hospitaloutcome`.

Comment: @user2554330 hospital outcome is the original dataframe and outcome is the variable. Does it matter to have a variable that is close in name to something else?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you used `stateusecols$outcome` later.  That won't work; you need to write it as `stateusecols[,outcome, drop = TRUE]` or it will look for a column named `"outcome"`.

Comment: Thank you @user2554330 I did not realize I could put the column name in []. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by @user2554330

By changing out all `$outcome` for `[,outcome,drop=TRUE]` the function now works.

Thanks!